# Re-writing a data.frame and replacing the values with their closest in a second data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame (`df.x`) which is composed of 1000 rows and 10 columns. The last column is a category/label for each row (i.e. `df.x$lbl`).

```
df.x <- data.frame(replicate(9,sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df.x$lbl <- (replicate(1,sample(0:15,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

Then I aggregate this data.frame to (`df.x.agg`) based "lbl" column. Now I have two data.frames:

```
df.x.agg <- aggregate(df.x[, 1:ncol(df.x)], list(df.x$lbl), mean)
df.x.agg <- df.x.agg[,2:ncol(df.x.agg)]
```

What I want to do is re-write every values of the first column `X1` in `df.x` by comparing each value of `df.x` with all values of the first column in `df.x.agg` and replace it with the label of that row in `df.x.agg` that has the closest value. This should be done for every column of `df.x`. So the output would be a new `df.x` (i.e. `new.df.x`) where it is filled with labels instead of numbers.

Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a fixed seed to generate sample data to ensure reproducibility.

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017)
df.x <- data.frame(replicate(9,sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df.x$lbl <- (replicate(1,sample(0:15,1000,rep=TRUE)))

df.x.agg <- aggregate(df.x[, 1:ncol(df.x)], list(df.x$lbl), mean)
df.x.agg <- df.x.agg[,2:ncol(df.x.agg)]


df.x.new <- mapply(
    function(x, y) apply(outer(x, y, function(v, w) abs(v - w)), 1, which.min) - 1,
    df.x[, -ncol(df.x)], df.x.agg[, -ncol(df.x.agg)])
head(df.x.new)
#     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
#[1,] 10 10  2  5  9 11  0 12  7
#[2,] 10 14  8  3 10  1  0  0  7
#[3,]  0 14 11  3 10  1  8 12  0
#[4,]  1 14  9 10 12  1  5 12  0
#[5,] 10  3 11  5  9  1  2 12  7
#[6,] 10  0 11 11  9  0  0 12  7
```

For every entry of `df.x`, `df.x.new` stores the `lbl` of the closest entry from the same column in `df.x.agg`. I define "closest" as the *absolute difference between two values*.

Cross-check: Take entry `df.x.new[1, 1] = 10`; we confirm that for `df.x$X1[1] = 93` the entry in `df.x.agg$X1` with `lbl = 10` is indeed the "closest"

```
df.x.agg$lbl[which.min(df.x$X1[1] - df.x.agg$X1)]
#[1] 10
```